# debug1: Exit status 0, when trying to ssh into a remote server

Tags: jenkins, ssh, centos

I am trying to scp some files and then ssh into a remote server. Works fine from localhost. However when I am trying the same through a shell script in Jenkins, the ssh session gets kinda stuck or closes. I tried running the scp command alone by hashing out the sab command and that works fine. I am receiving a debug1: Exit status 0 at the end of my Console Output.

The commands I'm trying to run are :

```
sshpass -p 0pen5ecret scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
/home/jenkins/test_folder/${env}_test.properties 
servername@${server}:/home/
```

and then,

```
sshpass -p password ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
servername@${server} 'cd /home ; rm -f cachefolder ; sh test.sh'
```

Below is the error message I am getting in Console Output :

```
debug1: Host '172.21.83.215' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard- 
interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 172.21.83.244 ([172.21.83.210]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /data01/DS_Release
Sending file modes: C0777 123 TS2_DeploymentScore.properties
Sink: C0777 123 TS2_DeploymentScore.properties
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3320, received 4596 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 54147.4, received 74958.3
debug1: Exit status 0
```

How can this be resolved ? Thanks in advance. Btw, this is my very first question here so be nice.

Comment: The console output that you posted shows what appears to be a successful attempt to `scp` a file named "TS2_DeploymentScore.properties" into "/data01/DS_Release" on the remote system. In particular, exit status 0 usually indicates success. It's not clear what problem you think you're having.

Comment: @Kenster Okay. Cool. But how do I know the ssh command that immediately follows the scp command is running as well  ? Since the output doesn't show any of it.

Comment: I got this resolved by using nohup. The shell doesn't keep hanging anymore. It exits once the commands are run with a Success message.

Answer (score 0):

To SCP file remotely over the server, you can use either of the two options:

1. If you are using Jenkins file, you can use stash and unstash feature of Jenkins:

   - create two stages in pipeline, run the first one on the source server and stash your files in that.
   - run the second stage on destination server and unstash your files in that server.
     (you need to install Jenkins agent on the server)
2. If you are using a freestyle job, you can use expect script to copy files remotely, you can use below syntax:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/expect -f

   #Usage sshsudologin.expect <host> <ssh user> <ssh password> <foldername>

   set timeout 20

   spawn scp  -r "/sourcefolder/[lindex $argv 3]" [lindex $argv 1]@[lindex $argv 0]:"/export/home/[lindex $argv 1]/"

   expect "yes/no" {
   send "yes\r"
   expect "*?assword" { send "[lindex $argv 2]\r" }
   } "*?assword" { send "[lindex $argv 2]\r" }


   expect eof
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer pal. I got this resolved by using nohup with my commands. The shell exits now with a Success message instead of hanging like it did earlier.